# Question about recruitment and careers

Tags: support, site-recommendation

As I remember there was a Stack Exchange site to post questions about recruitment and careers.
Does anyone remember what site that is?

Comment: Grrrrrr, Who down voted my question haaa? Every gentleman hurry up to up-vote against him. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site you are looking for is [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/), which triumphantly emerged from beta status 10 days ago.

From their [tour](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tour):

> - Specific issues encountered navigating a professional environment
> - Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered pertaining to a workplace

are both on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably thinking of [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) - which *originally* entertained those types of questions, and everything else that could conceivably be *about* programmers or asked in the context of being one.

When people started asking about whether or not you'd fart in a cubicle *as a programmer*, it came time for some major scope refactoring. Programmers now handles questions about *theoretical* software development problems, where you don't quite have a concrete implementation to show. However, careers-y, "as a programmer, how do you", "what should I learn next ..", etc are now considered to be [off-topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there.

Comment: Hi Tim, I Remember once I rad some post like, "My Boos did blah blah..... What should I do", "In my interview they ask blah blah blah questions, Why is that" somewhere in stackexchange. So I'm looking for that place. But I couldn't find such place in `http://stackexchange.com/`. Anyway finally there was no place for such questions now?

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya Are you looking for [The Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Wowwwwww Jonsca. You Got what is in my mind. thank you. that's what I was looking for. If you can add your comment as a answer. I can Mark it =).

Comment: Mystery solved, you're probably looking for The Workplace, which just got a shiny new design!! Go have a look :)

Comment: @Tim Post: Thank Man. I couldn't express it properly in my question =)